# Implement email functionality in C# .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I am trying to implement email functionality in a C# .NET Core console application. Whenever there is an error an email has to be sent out to the users. I am not sure how to implement this. Is there a .NET Core library to do this the simple way?

I tried using the Serilog.Sink.Email library, but it does not seem to work.

Here is my code.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                     // add console as logging target
                     .WriteTo.Console()
                     //.WriteTo.File(path: @"C:\Code\Test.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                     .WriteTo.File(path: @configuration.GetSection("LogPath").Value, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                     .WriteTo.Email(
                          from: "LOG",
                          to: "test@test.com",
                          host: "exchange",
                          subject: "Error Log",
                          restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error
                          )
                         
                     // set default minimum level
                     .MinimumLevel.Debug()                           
                     .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email

Comment: What's the question? You already posted the code that answers your question.  `it does not seem to work` isn't a problem description. I suspect the problem is `host: "exchange"`. This would only work if you're on a Windows network with an Exchange server named Exchange *AND* Exchange was configured to *NOT* use TLS, which is highly unlikely. The default SMTP port 25 is used for unencrypted connections. Almost all servers use TLS encryption by now, on port 587. You need to specify the correct host, port and credentials to send any email with any library